# Скрытие div в зависимости url

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте . Хочу скрыть div в зависимости url  как сделать ? Сделал так не получилось .

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          if( window.location.href = 'http://adres'){
                $('.tttt').hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все извиняюсь исправил дело в том что jquery не правильно подключил

Comment: @fikos, у вас там скрипты по 2 раза загружаются все и jquery в том числе :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.href === 'http://adres')
```

Comment: снова не сработало @Etki

Answer (score 0):

[[@fikos](/users/18880/fikos)](/users/18880/fikos) посмотрите, чему равен ваш 'window.location.href' и посмотрите с чем сравниваете. А еще лучше распарсить URL и сравнивать то что нужно, а не весь URL целиком, чтобы не привязываться к домену

Comment: window.location.href выводит http://vortex.az/wp/  а я при ровнял === 'http://vortex.az/wp/'  @inferusvv